# ¿Qué debo hacer para imprimir una lista de múltiplos de cuatro y que vaya del mayor al menor en c?

Tags: c, bucle-for

```
/* Programa: Números múltiplos de 4 que vaya del mayor al menor */

//#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numero;
    printf( "\n   " );

    for (...){
        printf( "%d ", numero );
    }
    //getch(); /* Pausa */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código que muestras?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
for(int i = 10; i >= 1; i--){
    printf("%d\n",i*4);
}
```

Esto mostrará los múltiplos de 4 empezando por 40 y terminando en 4, para personalizar la cantidad de números a mostrar, en lugar de "10" en el bucle "for", puedes colocar la cantidad que ingrese el usuario como una variable de entrada de tipo int.

Answer (score 1):

La manera adecuada de hacerlo en lenguaje C es la siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int veces = 10,numero = 4, i = 0;
    for(i=veces;i>=1;i--){
        printf("%d\n",i*numero);
    }
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente del anterior codigo:

- En lenguaje C no funciona declarar el iterador dentro del `for`.
- La librería `<stdio.h>` permite usar `printf` y `scanf`
- Se va reduciendo el iterador a medida que se ejecuta cada ciclo, hasta llegar a un numero mayor o igual a  1.

Puedes hacer un `scanf()` para solicitar al usuario cuantos múltiplos quiere y de que numero los desea. Quedando así el programa:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int veces = 0,numero = 0, i = 0;
    printf("Por favor ingrese el numero del cual desea ver sus multiplos: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    printf("\nPor favor ingrese cuantos multiplos desea ver: ");
    scanf("%d",&veces);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=veces;i>=1;i--){
        printf("%d\n",i*numero);
    }
}
```

Comment: El iterador si se puede declarar dentro del `for` a partir de las últimas versiones del estándar de C.